# Why do we get $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left\lbrack K^2 {\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)}^n -...\right]$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have this equivalency:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(K^2 -12\right){\left(12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2t+K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t\right)}^n \;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\;\mathrm{dt}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left\lbrack K^2 {\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)}^n -{\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)}^{n+1}\right\rbrack\mathrm{dt}$$
where $K$and $n$ are constants.

How is the first integral transformed into the second one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$K^2 {\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)}^n -{\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)}^{n+1}\\
=\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)^n[K^2-(K^2\sin^2t+12\cos^2t)]\\
=\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)^n[K^2(1-\sin^2t)-12\cos^2t]\\
=\left(K^2 {\mathrm{sin}}^2 t+12\;{\mathrm{cos}}^2 t\right)^n(K^2-12)\cos^2t$$

Comment: (－‸ლ) Thanks! :-)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Victor Quezada I found that ლ is a letter of the georgian alphabet. For my personal culture, could you say what is the meaning attached to it in this context ? Thank you in advance.!

Comment: According to Google, (－‸ლ) is the ASCII representation of "facepalm" https://www.fastemoji.com/Emoticon-Emoji-Face-Palm-Ascii-Art-Meme-Face-Palm-Sadface-Japanese-Kaomoji-Smileys-82.html

Comment: @Victor Quezada Thanks. I wasn't thinking to this possibility!